# How to sort a field multiple times?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table [hobbies] which looks like this:

```
id        hobby        skills          organization
-------------------------------------------------------
1         reading      encoding        greenpeace
2         cooking      web design      red cross
3         baking       programming     convoy of hope
```

And I want to have a query with a result like this:

```
 hobby        skills          organization
------------------------------------------------
 reading      programming     greenpeace
 cooking      web design      red cross
 baking       encoding        convoy of hope
```

hobby is sorted by id in ascending, skills is sorted also by id in descending and lastly organization is sorted by id in ascending.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: This is possible (are you familiar with window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`?) but I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do this... This defeats the entire purpose of storing the data the way you've stored it... If, for example, baking has no relation to programming, then why are they stored in the same row against the same ID? You should probably rethink the way you've structured your data here rather than looking for a solution like this, IMO.

Comment: Sounds like you probably want an ID and a category - or maybe just an ID - either way you probably don't want to store multiple disparate pieces of data in the same table just so they can share an ID.

Comment: I know. I'm not the one who designed this tables. Now I'm having a hard time using this tables in my programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very strange organisation of data, but if you insist, it can be done, for example, using `ROW_NUMBER` function.

**Sample data** - I've added `employeenumber` that you mentioned in the comments.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
id int, 
hobby nvarchar(255), 
skills nvarchar(255), 
organization nvarchar(255), 
employeenumber int);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(11, 'reading', 'encoding   ', 'greenpeace    ', 123),
(12, 'cooking', 'web design ', 'red cross     ', 123),
(13, 'baking ', 'programming', 'convoy of hope', 123),
(21, 'reading', 'encoding   ', 'greenpeace    ', 222),
(22, 'cooking', 'web design ', 'red cross     ', 222),
(23, 'baking ', 'programming', 'convoy of hope', 222);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        id
        ,hobby
        ,skills
        ,organization
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rn_asc
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn_desc
    FROM @T AS hobbies
    WHERE employeenumber = 222
)
SELECT
    C1.id
    ,C1.hobby
    ,C2.skills
    ,C1.organization
FROM
    CTE AS C1
    INNER JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C2.rn_desc = C1.rn_asc
ORDER BY C1.rn_asc;
```

**Result**

```
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
| id |  hobby  |   skills    |  organization  |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
| 21 | reading | programming | greenpeace     |
| 22 | cooking | web design  | red cross      |
| 23 | baking  | encoding    | convoy of hope |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Where can I add a Condition for a particular employeenumber? I forgot to include it in the table.

Comment: @ylleigh12, what is `employeenumber`? Is it just another column in the `hobbies` table?

Comment: @ylleigh12, it looks like simple `WHERE employeenumber = 123` should be enough. I've updated the answer.

Comment: tried that already but the result came back looking like the original table where the skills is sorted by id in ascending.

Comment: @ylleigh12, I've added sample data and result to my answer. If this result is not what you expect, please update the question and explain what you need in more details.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how tables work. Each of your tuples, (id, hobby, skills, organization) constitutes a row. You can change the order of (entire) rows, but not sort the columns independently and on arbitrary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how tables work, but it is possible to accomplish this.  One method is aggregation and `union all`:

```
select max(hobby) as hobby, max(skills) as skills,
       max(organization) as organization
from ((select row_number() over (order by id asc) as seqnum, hobby, NULL as skills, organization
       from hobbies
      ) union all
      (select row_number() over (order by id desc), NULL, skills, NULL
       from hobbies
      )
     ) h
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```